# Android 8.0 associate app with file extension

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I have a custom file type/extension associated with my app.

I add  to Android manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="file"
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="*/*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.iwf" />
        </intent-filter>
```

This code worked fine on android 4.3.
But on android 8.0 system write "There is no installed app that can open this attachment ..." 
Any ideas?

Comment: See [Android 7.0 behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#perm) - newer email applications no longer query for `file` uri, they use `content` scheme with appropriate `mimetype` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I will be read you reference more deep and I will try scheme="content"